# How to refer C++ Lambda from another source file?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, c++11, lambda

Now, I'm struggling to refer the lambda in another *.cpp file. But, I don't know how to implement it.

Suppose I have a lambda function which locates in money.cpp, then, how can I refer it in my dollar.cpp?

Anybody can help me? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my lambda function:

```
auto MaxComDiv = [](int num1, int num2) mutable -> int
{
    int remainder;
    while(remainder = num1 % num2)
    {
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = remainder;
    }
    return num2;
}
```

**Update:**
In fact, I'm learning C++ 11 recently, and these code manner is not allowd in our real work. The goal of the question is that, I want to try something new, it's just one of my practice.

In software category, we must keep learning until we retire.

Comment: Just make a regular function...

Comment: I think that is not the idea for using lambda functions..., the idea is to avoid to declare a class or a function when you're passing pointers to a function or when you're using a class wrapping a function functionality

Comment: @ DGomez, No, I don't think so. My code is legal in C++ 11. I write these code because I love Lambda.

Comment: Agree with GManNickG and DGomez. You can't name the type of a lambda, so how would you extern it? But more fundamentally, that's not the point of them.

Comment: Using lambdas simply because you "love lambdas" is not a good enough reason. It would be different if you wanted to make `MaxComDiv` assignable from outside `money.cpp`, though (although even in that case a function pointer would work well).

Comment: You can declare regular functions almost like lambdas, but what's the point? If it's a learning experience, ok, but if you have to touch code in a professional environment I think your coworkers would be justifiably annoyed with you for doing it.

Comment: @Joel, yes, you are right. They want to kill me because of these C++ lambda code. Very sad!

Comment: @Triumphant: Your code is surely legal C++11, but as you can see lambdas have some uses and are not really good for others. For example, being able to call a lambda from a different translation unit to where it was created requires doing type erasure (`std::function`) and that does not come for free. Additionally by not using the usual C++11 constructs, you are making your code harder to maintain.

Comment: Yes, the code is valid C++11. So what? Here's some more valid C++11 code that uses lambdas `int main() { <:]{%>; }`.

Comment: If you have a new question, you should click on the "Ask a Question" button rather than nuking your old question.

Comment: @Triumphant: can't do as I did not down vote. Down votes should reflect the question for itself, the fact that the approach is flawed should be a reason to suggest other approaches, but not to down vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make `MaxComDiv` global, add a declaration to a header `money.h`, like this:

```
extern function<int(int,int)> MaxComDiv;
```

You need to `#include <functional>` in order for this to compile.

Comment: This is no longer a lambda, but rather a type erasure object containing a lambda.

Comment: @Yakk OP can still access `MaxComDiv` across translation unit's boundary, call it, and assign a new lambda or another kind of a function object to it. What's the point to mention the distinction then?

Comment: among other things, performance: `std::function` has a call overhead similar to a `virtual` method, or more than calling a function via function pointer.  A lambda instance, meanwhile, basically has zero call overhead, as callers of the closure know what function they are calling from their own type signature.  Calling `std::function` the  type of a lambda is a common misconception that has runtime costs if you do not know it to be a lie.

Comment: @Yakk I am yet to encounter a real-life situation when a performance "overhead" of a `virtual` call would make a slightest bit of a difference. The difference between virtual and non-virtual calls inevitably turned to be a worthless exercise in premature micro-optimization. What are "the other things" that you suggest may be of relevance here?

Comment: @daslinkenlight I can write a loop that compiles down to a single constant with a lambda, and runs for many seconds if you used a `std::function`.  0 second execution: https://ideone.com/VmYhJC time limit exceeded: https://ideone.com/4EJjTm difference?  one uses `std::function`, the other raw lambdas. For real life situations: any per-pixel per-frame operations should avoid `virtual` overhead, even today.

Comment: as for other things, accuracy.  Lambdas are anonymous types with inline operators which lack a trivial constructor and have an `operator()` and can be copy constructed only from themselves.  `std::function<>`s are type erasure objects that can be constructed or assigned from any object which permits their call signature and do internal allocation and storage of a copy of said objects, calling them when they themselves are invoked with their `operator()`.  They are not the same thing.  Exception safety differs between them, and lambdas don't allocate on the free store.

Comment: @Yakk I am not talking about constructing a specific example to demonstrate that `virtual` overhead does exist, only about real-life scenarios where it would matter. Per-pixel per-frame and other tight loop scenarios do exist, but they are few and far between. You don't suppose the OP was planning to run Euclidean algorithm per-pixel per frame, right?

Comment: @Yakk As far as the other distinctions are concerned, they are of hair-splitting nature. Besides, OP never asked for a way to use a lambda as a lambda, only for a way to refer to a lambda in another translation unit - presumably, for the purpose of calling it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to declare the lambda as an actual function.

Comment: yes, i already know that, and i won't write such code.

Comment: @Triumphant Are you trying to make your code as convoluted as possible?

Comment: Of course not, in fact, i'm just learning C++ 11, and want to try something new. lambda in C++ 11 is wonderful. the question is one my practice.

Comment: @Triumphant Then you should learn that this is a very bad use of  lambdas.

Comment: Yes, already konw that.